# Pivot Pandas dataframe to see if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame that represents whether a User was present in some week, some year:

```
    User    Year    Week
0   John    2020    1
1   John    2020    2
2   Steve   2020    1
3   Fred    2020    3
4   George  2020    2   
5   George  2020    3
    ...     ...     ...
200 John    2021    2
201 John    2021    4
202 Steve   2021    2
203 Fred    2021    2
204 George  2021    1   
205 George  2021    4
```

I want to get a DataFrame that groups the dataset by `User` and each column represents whether he was present in a certain week of a certain year, each column either being of type boolean or integer with possible values 0 or 1.

It would look something like this:

```
        2020_1  2020_2  2020_3  ... 2021_1  2021_2  2021_3  2021_4
John         1       1       0  ...      0       1       0       1
Steve        1       0       0  ...      0       1       0       0
Fred         0       0       1  ...      0       1       0       0
George       0       1       1  ...      1       0       0       1
```

Is there anyway to do this without iterating through the DataFrme?

Thanks.

Comment: The solution from all 3 were amazing. I learnt something new. Thx to all 3 SO members on the answer. +1 to all 3 and to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new column and use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['User'],
            df[['Year','Week']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
           )
```

Output:

```
col_0   2020_1  2020_2  2020_3  2021_1  2021_2  2021_4
User                                                  
Fred         0       0       1       0       1       0
George       0       1       1       1       0       1
John         1       1       0       0       1       1
Steve        1       0       0       0       1       0
```

Comment: Right, but I still need to fill it with the corresponding value depending on whether the using was present or not that year and week

Comment: I don't get it, did you try my code? What do you don't like about it?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didn't make myself clear: even if there aren't any users that were present in "year_week", I'd like that column to exist. In my example, nobody was present in `2021_3`, but I'd like that column to be there

Comment: @Heathcliff Explore `reindex` after the `crosstab`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "User" : ["John","John","Steve","Fred","George","George"],
    "Year" : [2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
    "Week": [1,2,1,3,2,3]})

# add a helper column for year_week
df["year_week"] = df["Year"].map(str) + "_" + df["Week"].map(str)

# group by User and year_week, then unstack and fill NaN with 0
df.groupby(["User","year_week"]).size().unstack(fill_value = 0)
```

Results in:

```
| User   |   2020_1 |   2020_2 |   2020_3 |
|:-------|---------:|---------:|---------:|
| Fred   |        0 |        0 |        1 |
| George |        0 |        1 |        1 |
| John   |        1 |        1 |        0 |
| Steve  |        1 |        0 |        0 |
```

Comment: use `unstack(fill_value=0)` will keep the data type as `int`.

Comment: Hey! That's dope @QuangHoang. Learn something new evey day.

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.crosstab(df.User, df['Year'].astype(str)+"_"+df['Week'].astype(str))
```